# Get file descriptor output in resumed syscall using strace

Tags: linux, system-calls, file-descriptor, unix-socket, strace

I am using command:

```
sudo strace --trace=sendto,recvfrom,read,write,ipc -yy -s 10000 -fp $pid 2>&1
```

where pid is the the process id I want to trace.

When i get outputs, there are some unfinished and resumed syscalls.

The unfinished syscall looks like this:

```
[pid  4427] recvfrom(82<UNIX:[2715572>2716112,"/home/learn/my_socket"]>,  <unfinished...>
```

And the resumed syscall looks like this:

```
[pid  4427] <... recvfrom resumed>"\0\20{\"isAlive\":true}", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 18
```

I want to know the file descriptor information `82<UNIX:[2715572>2716112,"/home/learn/my_socket"]` also in the resumed syscall.

How can I possibly do that?

Comment: I think it will always be the FD from the most recent unfinished call.

Comment: Actually, I am doing a grep for the path to my_socket, so the resumed calls get misssed and I keep getting incomplete data.

Comment: I don't think you can change the way it formats the output, so you'll have to do something more complex than just grep.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, my idea is to use `awk`. When the line contains `<unfinished...>` save the FD in a variable. When it contains `resumed>` add the FD to the output.